# inserting variable from actionscript into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, flash, uploadify, user-agent

I am using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to insert the browser and OS of users who upload files to my website into a MySQL table.  I am using uploadifive, which has a fallback to using flash (uploadify) for browsers that don't support HTML5.  When using Flash, the OS and browser are not returned using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], instead I see "Adobe Flash Player 11".

I can see from [this tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-detect-the-browser-and-user-agent-with-as3/) that I can add some actionscript to the uploadify flash file to return the browser.  An ExternalInterface.call returns the same info as $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], which is stored in the userAgent variable.  I am not sure how to integrate this with the insertion into the MySQL database though.  I need one argument for inserting into a field in the MySQL table.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: can you elaborate on "I need one argument for inserting into a field in the MySQL table"? Are you actually getting both variables? ExternalInterface.call just calls JS, so are you already got this to server?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, I just need one line for insertion into my MSQL table, to replace `'".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."',`. Are you saying to just use JS to get the user agent rather than PHP?  If so I would need the js script from the tutorial on the page that users are uploading files on, as well as in the actionscript, wouldn't I?

Comment: I don't think you can piggyback extra information on a file upload call, but you probably return information back in response to it. You'll probably need to make a separate call to store the server information, tying it to the upload with the return from the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the userAgent with javascript via `navigator.userAgent`

In Uploadify there should be a js similar to the following:
In this example the server file is uploadify.php, so you can easily 
pass values like in any other url.

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php' + '?ua=' + encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent)
    });
});
```

So in uploadify.php you can access the user agent via

`$_GET['ua']`

Now you just have to check which input variable is actually assigned:

```
$userAgent = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] && false === strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Adobe Flash Player') {
    $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
} else {
    $userAgent = $_GET['ua'];
}
```

So you can use $userAgent in your mysql statement.
 But don´t forget to escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string` (or use PDO binding):

```
$userAgent = mysql_real_escape_string($userAgent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an IO Error though when attempting an upload with uploadify having added `'script'    : '/uploadify_test/uploadify.php' + '?ua=' + navigator.userAgent,` to my uploadify script.

Comment: Try to escape the userAgent string with `+ encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent)`. If it fails try it with a simple value, say + '1'. If that works, try to figure out, what navigator.userAgent is giving you (via firebug console: `alert (navigator.userAgent);´ I think it´s a issue with flash, having problems with spaces/special chars in the url string.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding encodeURIComponent and it still failed.  Adding + 1 worked.  `alert (navigator.userAgent);` returned Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2